# How to use twilio with Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, twilio-api

I want to send a WhatsApp message to a particular number when a Firebase Realtime Database is triggered. But unable to implement the code properly -

```
const accountSid = 'AC565656563389214ace8531'; 
const authToken = '[AuthToken]'; 
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 
 
client.messages 
      .create({ 
         body: 'Your appointment is coming up on July 21 at 3PM, 
         from: 'whatsapp:+1415454545386',       
         to: 'whatsapp:+9196456454566' 
       }) 
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid)) 
      .done();
```

I want to use this code in Firebase function for the trigger in the Realtime database.

Comment: there is an extension if you are using Firebase and Twilio

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Use one of the options detailed in the doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)
// for storing the two following secrets
const accountSid = ...
const authToken = ...

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/.../{pushId}')  // Adapt the path 
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {  // Adapt the trigger? E.g. OnWrite?

        return client.messages
            .create({
                body: 'Your appointment is coming up on July 21 at 3PM',
                from: 'whatsapp:+1415454545386',
                to: 'whatsapp:+9196456454566'
            })
            .then(message => {
                console.log(message.sid);
                return null;
            });
});
```

Comment: Hey @BhaskarJyotiDutta, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?